# Dividing integer by all numbers in a range in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script that divides an integer by all numbers in a range and have a value of true only if all numbers are to 0 decimal places.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
n = int(input("Please enter a number (more than 0) :"))
count = 0


if n < 1 : print("Please enter a positive number")
else:
    if n%2 == 0 : print("Number is not prime")
    else:

        for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1):
                if i % n == 0 :
                    count = count + 1
                    count = count + 0

if count > 1 : print("Number is not prime")
else : print("Number is prime")
```

It prints Number is prime for any odd number.

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that removing the line beginning `if n%2 == 0`... and having your `for` loop begin at 2 would work just as fine, if not better.

Comment: Another problem is: 1 is shown as a prime number and it is not. How could this be shown as not a prime number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong on two counts -

```
        for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1):
            if n%i == 0 : # You want to check if n is divisible by i
                count = count + 1
                # No need of count = count + 0 here since it does nothing

if count > 0 : print("Number is not prime") # Prime if count > 0 & not count > 1
else : print("Number is prime")
```

Also, you can improve the code by running the `for` loop in steps of 2 rather than 1 i.e. check if n is divisible by all odd numbers from 3 to sqrt(n) instead of all numbers from 3 to sqrt(n).

```
for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2): # The 3rd argument indicates steps
```

Comment: Thanks for all responses. It was because i % n == 0 was incorrect haha. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you find that my answer was right & complete, please **accept** it & close the question.

Answer (score 1):

`if count > 1 : print("Number is not prime")` should be `if count >= 1 : print("Number is not prime")`. Also, in `if n%2 == 0 : print("Number is not prime")`, `count` should be incremented. Better, why even have `if n%2 == 0 : print("Number is not prime")`? Change 3 in `for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1):` to 2, and that if statement can be removed.

**PS**: `count = count + 0` does nothing, so remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = int(input("Type a number: "))  

isprime = 'true'                

for x in range(2, inp):
    y = (inp % x)
    if y == 0:
        isprime = 'false'

print(isprime)
```

Comment: While I'm marking this question as "Looks OK", you should know that code-only answers are looked down upon here. Please try to add some explanation to this answer and other answers you may post later.